# How to rotate every letter in a title

Tags: theme-development, filters, css

I was wondering how to rotate every letter in a title.

You can rotate every letter in a word with

```
<span class="slant">A</span class="slant">
<span class="slant">c</span class="slant">
<span class="slant">m</span class="slant">
```

with the CSS

```
.slant {transform: rotate(10deg); }
```

But how to do it with WordPress?

I was thinking use JavaScript/jQuery to split the `<?php bloginfo("url")?>` into letters, add the slant class and put the css in the `style.css` section.

Comment: #joao..might be this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864676/is-it-possible-to-rotate-characters-of-a-word-instead-of-rotating-the-whole-word) helps you

Comment: you can use rotate in wordpress also

Comment: Your original thinking is indeed how you should do it or use @cjbj 's solution for a proper WordPress way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jquery to split the title into letters and apply the class. That would work for any html page, regardless whether it was made by WordPress, Drupal, some dude that is stuck with Dreamweaver or whatever.

The WP way would be different. If you're new this is fairly complex, but a good start if you're willing to learn. The title of a WP post is generated by a function called [`get_the_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/). This function ends with a filter, that [allows you to modify](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) the resulting title. Like this, which you would put in the `functions.php` file of your [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes):

```
add_filter ('the_title', 'wpse263471_split_title');
function wpse263471_split_title ($title) {
  ... do stuff ...
  return $title;
  }
```

In the place of 'do stuff' you would have to [write php code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) that splits `$title` into letters, adds `<span class=slant>` around them and then glues `$title` together before returning it.